# Deleted Git tags restore themselves

Tags: git, git-remote, git-tag

We recently ran into an issue with tags in our Git repository.

We deleted our tags locally and remotely, yet they kept restoring itself every time we either push to or fetch from remote.

We are currently working in a team of three and when we think we actually got rid of the tags, someone would do a push and we all get them again.

We all tried:

```
git tag -d 12345
git push origin :refs/tags/12345
```

Anyone else ran into this issue?

Answer (score 10):

Delete the tags again and then do this:

```
# verify that the tag was removed form another computer
git fetch --all --prune
```

---

#### ***`Important`***

If you are on an older version of git `<2.0` git push without branch name might push all your `branches & tags` to the remote. Verify that this is not the case here.

---

#### ***`What else can you try?`***

```
# push just the tag name without refs/tags/...
git push origin :tagname

# same as above but with the `--delete` flag instead of `:`
git push --delete origin tagname

# as you already did locally - delete the tag as well
git tag -d tagname
```

---

#### ***`Git hooks`***

Verify that there are no git hooks which block you from delete the tags.
Here is a sample hook which do it:

```
#!/bin/sh

log() { printf '%s\n' "$*"; }
error() { log "ERROR: $*" >&2; }
fatal() { error "$*"; exit 1; }

case $1 in
    refs/tags/*)
        [ "$3" != 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 ] \
            || fatal "you're not allowed to delete tags"
        [ "$2" = 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 ] \
            || fatal "you're not allowed to move tags"
        ;;

    # personal touch :-)
    echo "                                         "
    echo "                   |ZZzzz                "
    echo "                   |                     "
    echo "                   |                     "
    echo "      |ZZzzz      /^\            |ZZzzz  "
    echo "      |          |~~~|           |       "
    echo "      |        |-     -|        / \      "
    echo "     /^\       |[]+    |       |^^^|     "
    echo "  |^^^^^^^|    |    +[]|       |   |     "
    echo "  |    +[]|/\/\/\/\^/\/\/\/\/|^^^^^^^|   "
    echo "  |+[]+   |~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~|    +[]|   "
    echo "  |       |  []   /^\   []   |+[]+   |   "
    echo "  |   +[]+|  []  || ||  []   |   +[]+|   "
    echo "  |[]+    |      || ||       |[]+    |   "
    echo "  |_______|------------------|_______|   "
    echo "                                         "
    echo "                                         "
    echo "      This is your last time trying to   " 
    echo "      delete or to move our tags. :-)    "
    echo "                                         "

esac
```

---

> ## Git v2.0 Release Notes
>
> ### Backward compatibility notes
>
> When `git push [$there]` does not say what to push, we have used the
>   traditional ***`matching`*** semantics so far (all your branches were sent
>   to the remote as long as there already are branches of the same name
>   over there).  In Git 2.0, the default is now the ***`simple`*** semantics,
>   which pushes:
>
> - only the current branch to the branch with the same name, and only
>     when the current branch is set to integrate with that remote
>     branch, if you are pushing to the same remote as you fetch from; or
> - only the current branch to the branch with the same name, if you
>     are pushing to a remote that is not where you usually fetch from.
>
> You can use the configuration variable `push.default` to change
>   this.  If you are an old-timer who wants to keep using the
>   ***`matching`*** semantics, you can set the variable to ***`matching`***, for
>   example.  Read the documentation for other possibilities.

Comment: Thanks, will try the pruning.  We're on "git version 2.5.4 (Apple Git-61)"

Comment: Also try the second part of the answer as well if its not working for you still

Comment: Pruning did not work.  Deleted tags locally+remotely, then prune.  None of us had the tags. Good.  Then, we made a small code change, pushed to origin, and the tags came back.

Comment: Will attempt the other options.

Comment: So did it worked for you or not. i did not understand.

Comment: Maybe you have hooks that prevents you from delete it?

Comment: We do have a hook on Github that triggers a Jenkins build upon push.  As far as I know though, it doesn't affect the remote git repo.

Comment: More information:  We are building an iOS app that includes several cocoapods.  Would it be possible tags from other open source repo interfere with this?  However, some of the tags that keep appearing are our own so it isn't isolated to 3rd party tags.

Comment: `git fetch --all --prune` worked for me. Thank you very much! Those zombie tags were driving me nuts.

Answer (score 1):

A handy way to solve this problem for all tags at once :

**1) To be done ONCE, from any one of the local repos**

```
git push <remoteName> :<tagToDelete>
# (for example) git push origin :tag_foo_bar
```

**2) Then, to be done from EACH local repo involved**

```
git tag -d `git tag -d` && git fetch -t
```

This will list then delete all local copies of the repo's tags, then get them back anew from the remote.